# Angular universal build failure while using ng-packagr?

Tags: typescript, angular-universal, ng-packagr

I have used **ng-packagr** to create angular package for my control. it is created like beauty. but if i use that package in angular-universal sample, it throws following error while bundling

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids/@syncfusion/ej2- 
angular-grids.es5.js
Module parse failed: Identifier '__extends' has already been declared 
(1836:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     }
| }
| import { __extends } from "tslib";
| var __decorate$1 = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators,  
target, key, desc) {
|     var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = 
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
```

If i **create normal angular-cli,** there also same problem occurs but i have solved with upgrading compiler-cli package but in universal not able to solve this.

> ng-packagr configuration

**ng-package.json**

```
{
 "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "./public_api.ts"
  },
  "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
    "syncfusion",
    "typedoc", "angular"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
        "packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json"
    }
```

> It throws ts-lib error, i want to solve this or i want know how to disable **ts-lib** in ng-packagr